# Access the SharePoint online webservice from a console application

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-services, console-application

I tried to access a SharePoint Online web service i.e (/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx). I used the code sample provided in the following article :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2011/05/14/part-2-headless-authentication-with-sharepoint-online-and-the-client-side-object-model.aspx

But this gives an error

The security timestamp is invalid because its creation time ('2013-11-29T08:23:58.000Z') is in the future. Current time is '2013-11-29T08:16:38.706Z' and allowed clock skew is '00:05:00'.

Anyone faced this issue? Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method with which you are trying to authenticate is outdated. The SharePoint 2013 Client Object Model has now a class called `SharePointOnlineCredentials` which abstracts away all the tedious cookie container stuff. Eg:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/"))
{
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();

    foreach (char c in "yourpassword".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);

    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("loginname@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);

    Web web = clientContext.Web;

    clientContext.Load(web);

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    Console.WriteLine(web.Title);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Read more about it here:

http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/01/authenticating-net-client-object-model.html

Comment: Thanks Vardhaman 
It worked :) Thanks again